# Django. That IP address can't be assigned to

Tags: python, django, ssh, ip, production

I am trying to deploy a Django app. I have a server with a public ip such as 194.61.xx.xxx but when I execute `python3 manage.py runserver --noreload --nothreading 194.61.xx.xxx:8000` I get the error `Error: That IP address can't be assigned to.`.

I have already set `ALLOWED_HOSTS=["*"]` and I can connect using ssh to my server with no problem.

Comment: use  default `127.0.0.1:8000`, then it should be available in  `194.61.xx.xxx` with proper configurations

Comment: May you explain these configurations?

Comment: Try `0.0.0.0:8000` , before make sure  `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']` in the settings

Comment: Then it starts properly, but when i send a request to 194.61.xx.xxx, it is not received in the server.

Comment: what about `194.61.xx.xxx:8000`?

Comment: Then I get "Error: That IP address can't be assigned to."

Comment: I meant to send a request to `194.61.xx.xxx:8000`after running it through `0.0.0.0:8000`

Comment: Yes, in that case the server doesn't receive the request